# How do I say that I'm studying to become a Primary School teacher?

Tags: grammar, verbs

I want to say that I'm studying to become a teacher, I'm going to get a degree, a Bachelor's degree on Primary Education. Would it be correct to say "I'm doing a Bachelor's degree on Primary Education"? Or how would I have to say it?

Answer (score 2):

It is much better to say "a Bachelor's degree **in** Primary Education".

[image]

"Primary Education" is all right but the lower case version is used  more often.

[image]

Comment: Agreed. I have never heard the phrase “a degree on…”. The questioner is perhaps confusing it with “a course on …”. We follow a course on statistics but study for a degree in statistics.